# Repeated capture group and lazy issue

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to capture "foo" and any occurrence of "bar". Plus, I need to ignore any string between them and bar is optional.

Example text:

```
foo ignoreme barbarbar
foo ignoreme bar
foo ignoreme 
foo something abcbar
```

Expected:

```
foo barbarbar
foo bar
foo
foo bar
```

A tried with this regex :

```
(foo)(?:.*)((?:bar)*)
```

But the `.*` capture all the end of the string:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

So I changed it to lazy to stop the capture:

```
(foo)(?:.*?)((?:bar)*)
```

I almost got the same result, only foo is captured.

It seems it stop the capture to early, however, this almost works:

```
(foo)(?:.*?)((?:bar)+)

foo barbarbar
foo bar
<miss third line>
foo bar
```

But it misses the third line because the pattern "bar" must appear one time.
Example here https://regex101.com/r/NIUPew/1

Any idea from a regex guru? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the repeated capturing group into the non-capturing group while making that group optional:

```
(foo)(?:.*?((?:bar)+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWAM7n/1).

*Details*:

- `(foo)` - Group 1: `foo`
- `(?:.*?((?:bar)+))?` - an optional non-capturing group that will be tried at least once (because `?` is a greedy quantifier matching the quantified pattern one or zero times) to match

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
  - `((?:bar)+)` - Group 2: one or more `bar` char sequences.

Answer (score 1):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
(\bfoo) .*?(?: \w*?((?:bar)+)\w*)?$
```

and replace with:

```
$1 $2
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/szU3F9/4)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(\bfoo)`: 1st capture group to match `foo` after a word boundary
- `.*?`: Followed by a space any text (lazy match)
- `(?:` : Start non-capture group with a space

  - `\w*?`: Match 0 or more word chars (lazy)
  - `((?:bar)+)`: Match 1+ repetitions of `bar` in capture group #2
  - `\w*`: Match 0 or more word chars
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes this optional match
- `$`: End

PS: Regex can be shortened to `(\bfoo) .*?(?:((?:bar)+)\w*)?$` but it will be bit more slow.

Comment: Please check updated answer and new demo. `bar` is matched in first line also. If you don't want to substitute just use 2 capture groups as shown

Comment: Just for clarification what should be output for `foo something abcbar` ?

Comment: thanks, it should be : foo bar

Comment: ok check my updated regex & demo